# Orientação a Objetos (SUPER AJUDA)

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, microcontrolador

Segue uma pergunta que vai demandar uma resposta mais completinha, será que rola?

Reparem neste script que simula o comportamento de uma pessoa. A Classe é Pessoa e os métodos são os comportamentos possíveis. Alguém pode fazer uma analogia com cada atributo/sintaxe/parâmetro de uma classe já existente pra que fique ainda mais claro pra mim como funciona a construção dos códigos Python (?).

Entenderam?

Segue o código:

```
from datetime import datetime

class Pessoa:
    ano_atual = int(datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y'))

    def __init__(self, nome, idade, comendo=False, falando=False):
       self.nome = nome
       self.idade = idade
       self.comendo = comendo
       self.falando = falando

    def falar(self, assunto):
        if self.comendo:
            print(f'{self.nome} não pode falar comendo.')
            return

        if self.falando:
            print(f'{self.nome} já está falando.')
            return

        print(f'{self.nome} está falando sobre {assunto}.')
        self.falando = True


    def parar_falar(self):
        if not self.falando:
            print(f'{self.nome} não está falando')
            return

        print(f'{self.nome} parou de falar.')
        self.falando = False


    def comer(self, alimento):
        if self.comendo:
            print(f'{self.nome} já está comendo.')
            return

        if self.falando:
            print(f'{self.nome} não pode comer falando.')
            return

        print(f'{self.nome} está comendo {alimento}.')
        self.comendo = True


    def parar_comer(self):
        if not self.comendo:
            print(f'{self.nome} não está comendo.')
            return

        print(f'{self.nome} parou de comer.')
        self.comendo = False

    def get_ano_nascimento(self):
        return self.ano_atual - self.idade
```

Obrigado Devs!

PS. Um insight de iniciante: poderíamos usar este código no Back-end de um robô por exemplo, correto? Atrelando o código a funções eletrônicas. Alguém tem idéia de como isso poderia ser feito? Micro-controladores? Curiosidade (estou pesquisando em paralelo).

Comment: Poderia especificar melhor o que você gostaria que fosse explicado? ficou um pouco ampla

Comment: pois e - o código aí é auto-explicativo. Se você não entendeu alguma parte em específico, pergunte sobre ela. Criar uma outra classe, numa resposta, que fizesse algo parecido não parece que poderia esclarecer alguma coisa.

Comment: e se im, esse código seria perfeitament usável num micro-controlador ou computador embutido  - é ó ver o framework de Python na plataforma em que você estiver, e (1) criar uma instância dessa classe para ser o "Estado do sistema" - ou seja, essa instância vai representaro estado do aparelho todo e (2) ligar os métodos de "falar" , "parar de falar", etc... como callbacks a serem executados quando chegarem sinais de I/O. essa ligação é feita com alguma chamada do framework

Comment: Concordo com os demais - "fazer uma analogia com cada atributo/sintaxe/parâmetro de uma classe já existente pra que fique ainda mais claro pra mim como funciona a construção dos códigos Python" é uma pergunta muito ampla.

Comment: Coloquei um comentário mais abaixo devs.. na última resposta. Conseguem visualizar? Obrigado!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos lá:

Você tem a classe `Pessoa`, isso significa que é um "construtor" de pessoas. Você pode fazer:

```
maria = Pessoa()
joao = Pessoa()
dom_pedro_segundo = Pessoa()
```

Então `maria` passará a ter todas as características (atributos) e ações (métodos) que `Pessoa` tem.

Em `def __init__(self, nome, idade, comendo=False, falando=False):` você está informando o seguite, "é obrigatório na criação da `Pessoa` que ela tenha um `nome` e uma `idade` enquanto que `comendo` e `falando`, em sua ausência, são atributos (características) `False`, assim, no exemplo acima:

```
maria = Pessoa("Maria", 31) 
# A Pessoa acima tem o nome Maria e tem 31 anos de idade, não está falando e nem comendo

joao = Pessoa("João", 15,True) 
# A Pessoa acima tem o nome João e tem 15 anos de idade, está comendo mas não está falando

dom_pedro_segundo = Pessoa("Dom Pedro II", 195, falando=True)
# A Pessoa acima tem o nome Dom Pedro II e tem 195 anos de idade, não está comendo mas está falando
```

Em seguida temos uma série de funções (ou ações) da `Pessoa` em questão, ela pode `def falar` e pode `def parar_falar`, pode `def comer` e pode `def parar_comer`, poderia ter outros como `def andar`, `def correr`, `def parar`, `def dormir`, `def acordar`, `def pular`... Qualquer coisa que seja `def` é uma `def`inição da ação que a `Pessoa` é capaz de fazer.

**UPDATE**

Uma classe prática, além da classe pessoa, seria a classe Usuário.
Digamos que você quer fazer um sistema onde usuários tem cadastro (assim, eles tem um id/email e senha), nome, data de nascimento.

Se for um jogo, pode atribuir um rank, pontuação, classe, nickname, força, destreza, inteligencia... 
Se for uma rede social, pode atribuir lista de amigo, cidade, paginas que segue, lista de postagens... 
Se for financeiro (como um sistema de contabilidade pessoal de gastos para a família #fikdik), podemos por saldo, renda, profissão.

No caso do financeiro (finanças pessoais), parte do código (bem simples) seria algo como o abaixo, apenas considerando antes que as classes `Gasto` e `Ganho` estão no mesmo arquivo, se não, seria caso de fazer um

```
import Gasto
import Ganho
```

Enfim, o código seria:

```
class Usuario:

    def __init__(self, email, senha, data_nascimento, saldo=0, renda=0, profissao=None):
        self.email = email
        self.senha = senha
        self.data_nascimento = data_nascimento
        self.saldo = saldo
        self.renda = renda
        self.profissao = profissao

        self.historico = []
        self.logado = False

    def aumentar_renda(self):
        try:
            print("Entre com alguma das opções abaixo")
            print("1. Para somar um valor a renda\n2. Para alterar para o valor final da renda")
            escolha = int(input("--> "))
            if escolha == 1:
                valor = input("inseria a somar na renda: ")
                self.renda += float(valor)
                print(f"O valor adicionado foi {valor} e tua renda agora é {self.renda}!")
            elif escolha == 2:
                valor = input("Inseria o novo valor da tua renda")
                self.renda = float(valor)
                print(f"A tua renda agora é {self.renda}!")
            else:
                print("Escolha uma opção válida!")
        except:
            print("Escolha uma opção válida!")

    def alterar_saldo(self):
        print("Escolha uma das opções abaixo")
        print("1. Gasto\n2. Ganho")
        escolha = int(input("--> "))
        if escolha == 1:
            gasto = Gasto()
            self.historico.append(gasto)
            self.saldo -= gasto.valor
        elif escolha == 2:
            ganho = Ganho()
            self.historico.append(ganho)
            self.saldo += ganho.valor
        else:
            print('Escolha uma opção válida!')

class Gasto:

    def __init__(self):
        self.descricao = input("Insira a descrição do gasto: ")
        self.valor = float(input("Insia o valor do gasto: "))
        self.local = input("Inseria o local do gasto: ")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Descrição do gasto: {self.descricao} \nValor: {self.valor} \nLocal: {self.local}"

class Ganho:

    def __init__(self):
        self.descricao = input("Insira a descrição do ganho: ")
        self.valor = float(input("Insia o valor do ganho: "))
        self.local = input("Inseria o local do ganho: ")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Descrição do ganho: {self.descricao} \nValor: {self.valor} \nLocal: {self.local}"
```

Não estamos trabalhando com banco de dados para armazenar informação, o que tornaria os dados inseridos permanentes.

A chamada da função poderia ser algo como:

```
# Passei a data como texto para deixar mais simples a coisa
eu = Usuario("meu_email@gmail.com","UmaS3nhaB3mS3gura!!1!","01-01-2000")
```

A interação seria algo como

```
eu.alterar_saldo()

Escolha uma das opções abaixo
1. Gasto
2. Ganho
--> 2
Insira a descrição do ganho: Vendi meu carro
Insia o valor do ganho: 13000
Inseria o local do ganho: Feira de carro da cidade
```

E para ver o histórico (olhe que coloquei uma lista no atributo histórico, assim, você pode verificar o histórico de todos os gastos e ganhos que tem).

```
print(eu.historico[0])

Descrição do ganho: Vendi meu carro 
Valor: 13000.0 
Local: Feira de carro da cidade
```

**UPDATE2**

No caso, pode-se perguntar: "por que eu usaria um Objeto se um dicionário funcionaria da mesma maneira?". Essa é uma boa pergunta que eu mesmo já me fiz (o que me recusava a princípio a usar POO), até que senti a necessidade de uma coisa: manipulação e organização.

Você pode fazer tranquilamente o seguinte:

```
clientes = {"nome":["Maria", "João", "Dom Pedro II"],
            "idade":[31, 15, 195],
            "comendo":[False, True, False],
            "falando":[False, False, True]}
```

Até aqui, sem muitos problemas. Mas e se a lista começar a se estender mais? Por exemplo, eu tiver uma loja com 100 clientes? Uma lista com 100 itens seria difícil de ver as informações, também de acessar as informações específicas de cada um (acessar as informações da Maria sem ocorrer o erro de acessar do João), enquanto o POO, você pode fazer um dicionario também, como:

```
maria = Cliente("Maria", 31)
clientes = [{"maria":maria}, ...]
```

Você consegue acessar as informações da `Maria` apenas achando a chave certa, talvez seria mais interessante usar uma chave como o CPF como chave do dicionario, ficando algo como:

```
maria = Cliente("Maria", 31)
clientes = [{"098.765.432-10":maria}, ...]
```

Isso já resolveria totalmente o problema de acessar a informação correta, sem ficar se preocupando com os índices das listas internas. Mas este é o menor problema, a grande questão vem em **manipular as informações**.

Se, por exemplo, `maria` fez aniversário, e quiser adicionar adicionar + 1 a idade dela, como você faria? Teria que criar uma função externa `def envelhecer()` e teria que procurar uma característica chave, achar o índice onde estão as informações da `maria`, achar a chave certa e então alterar, se eu tenho uma classe, basta eu por esta função internamente e depois fazer `maria.envelhecer()` e Maria terá envelhecido 1 ano, assim como `joao.envelhecer()`, `dom_pedro.envelhecer()`, a mesma função para todos, mas este é o problema menor da manipulação.

O problema maior é quando você quiser **escalar** o teu código; e se ao invés de nome, idade, comer e falar, você quiser que as tenha o atributo `andar`, `comprar` (afinal, são clientes), `creditos_promocionais` (se os clientes estão participando de uma campanha promocional), `data_de_compras_e_valor` (para ter uma lista dos dias que o cliente visitou e comprou em tua loja, sabendo também o valor, para fazer um estudo do cliente e ofertar uma promoção que o agrade, talvez criando uma classe a parte só para isso).

Todas estas questões acima, não só envolvem expandir o número de chaves do dicionario que você teria, como também alterar as informações nelas contidas (além de preencher todos de forma adequada). Manipular e expandir um dicionário externamente de forma frequente pode suceder erros não previstos e indesejados, enquanto em uma classe, como as manipulações são padronizadas e internas a classe, tendem a ocorrer menos erros, todos os objetos da classe `Cliente` terão as mesmas características e serão padronizados estruturalmente, expandir não é um problema.

No caso, se já tiver adicionado os atributos(características "pessoais") e métodos (funções/ações), poderia fazer um `joao.data_de_compras_e_valor("01-02-2020",80.99)` e a informação já estará atualizada no objeto.

Na prática, a vantagem de um objeto, é trabalhar com volumes e volumes de dados usando pouco processamento. Claro que um POO não substitui um dicionário ou vice-versa, uma vez que uso bastante dicionários para informações fixas e que serão pouco ou nada alteradas, servindo justamente como um "de para", a exemplo acima, dos clientes onde passo uma chave uma chave-primária (CPF por exemplo) e o valor o objeto.

```
# Estrutura de um dicionário
dicio = {key:value} #{chave:valor}
clientes = {cpf:`Cliente`}
```

E usar uma lista para agregar estes dicionários:

```
clientes = [{"098.765.432-10":maria}, 
            {"987.654.321-09":joao}, 
            {"012.345.678-90":dom_pedro_segundo}]
```

Não existe recursos melhores ou piores, mas recursos apropriados para cada função. As coisas são excelentes para atender o propósito daquilo à que elas foram criadas, o paradigma da Orientação a Objeto é um, dicionários outro, banco de dados outros.

Como informei acima, não estou utilizando um banco de dados no exemplo, mas com um POO, seria mais fácil você conectar a tabela e acessar as informações certas, tudo padronizado, testado e de **FÁCIL MANUTENÇÃO** para você e terceiros.

E aproveitando a questão da manutenção, compartilhar código e trabalhar em equipe é muito melhor usando POO, pois todos trabalharão encima de um mesmo arquivo, sem a necessidade de ficar criando muitas subestruturas e arquivos a parte, tornando o trabalho mais fácil para você e outras pessoas que irão mexer em teu código.

Se tiver alguma dúvida, comenta esta resposta que eu faço alguns complementos a resposta.

Comment: Fala irmão! Acho que entendi s. A Classe é como se fosse um molde e você instancia alguma variável pra usar os métodos/atributos pertencentes a este 'molde', correto? Essa def __init__, não sei se a entendi bem. Os módulos tbm possuem essa extensão em Python, seria um tipo de diretório raiz do cód.? Outra coisa: não estou conseguindo fazer um paralelo com outras classes já existentes, list por exemplo: não possui nenhum parâmetro obrigatório. Alguns métodos pertencentes a esta classe sim. Pode me dar um ex. de uso de um parâmetro obrigatório para uma classe? Neste caso chamamos de atributo né?

Comment: Exato, as classes são moldes com características e ações pré-concebidas para serem preenchidas (nome, idade) e usadas (falar, comer).
Quanto ao def __init__, ele vem de initialization (inicializador), justamente onde ficarão as características iniciais, sem o __init__, você não tem os atributos iniciais (nome, idade) a serem definidos.

Quando diz "fazer um paralelo", você quer dizer uma interação entre elas? Quanto a lista, você pode usar um construtor interno def __iter__ para fazer iteração (criar uma lista), para tua classe poder se comportar como uma lista (ou parte dela).

Comment: Eu adicionei um UPDATE no meu código, se quiser saber algo mais, só falar que faço um UPDATE2

Comment: Incrível irmão. Na sua opinião, qual é a vantagem de eu usar esse paradigma ao invés de, por exemplo, criar um dicionário com essas informações? Outra coisa, concorda comigo que ao aprofundar em programação orientada a objetos vc passa a entender um pouco mais sobre o comportamento da linguagem?

Comment: Ainda sobre essa abordagem construtiva da linguagem que a POO nos dá, poderia exemplificar uma classe já existente com os seus atributos (variáveis de classe obrigatórias) e métodos internos?

Comment: Vou fazer um update2 falando do porque usar um POO ao invés de dicionários. Quanto a ultima pergunta, eu não entendi direito, porei especificar mais? Dependendo, pode rolar um update3

Comment: Eu vou fazer essa leitura agora, obrigado irmão. Enquanto isso, quando comentei mais acima sobre fazer um paralelo quis saber basicamente como funcionam esses conceitos dentro de uma classe já existente, para que eu pudesse colocar em perspectiva e entender melhor. Exemplo: a classe str tem como atributo básico o object=' ' vazio correto? Provavelmente o conteúdo desse atributo vai para dentro de self.conteúdo ou self.object ou seja lá qual for a nomenclatura usada para ser trabalhada dentro das funções internas da classe (métodos). Segue no próximo comentário...

Comment: Esse conteúdo é a string em si, que é enviada como parâmetro para o método len() por exemplo (me corrija se eu estiver errado). Logo, internamente, o Python trataria mais ou menos assim: def len (self, string = self.object, ....). O self.object que é o conteúdo associado na def __init__ que representa a string é passado como parâmetro dentro da def len. Ficou claro? hehe. O que eu estou tentando fazer é esse paralelo com classes existentes, daí mina conclusão anterior, quando disse que a POO ajuda a entender a construção interna da linguagem, não a toda as classes são chamadas de construtores.

Comment: Neste caso, você quer dizer sobre as funções reservadas como __str__, __init__, __iter__, __repl__? Ou no caso das hierarquias quando herda-se uma classe em outra? Pois não consegui entender bem o que quis dizer (desculpa, estou meio gripado [e não é coronavirus xD ])